# Change an input when you change another one in javascript

Tags: javascript, input, key-events

I have two input fields.
For example: One where you type in a color and another for the code of the color.

Like this: `|Green| |#008000|`

I do not want to learn how to find the color-code but how to match a value or variable with another. It was just an example.

What i wanna know is how I in the best way auto generate one of the fields when I fill in the second. When I type 'green' in the first field I want the code to automatically appear in the second and vice versa. I just want to do it for a few colors.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">

var inputA = document.getElementById("color");
var inputB = document.getElementById("code");

inputA.onkeyup = function() {
   var v = this.value.toLowerCase();
    if (colormapping.color2code[v]){
       inputB.value = colormapping.color2code[v];
    } else {
        inputB.value = '';
    }
   }
inputB.onkeyup = function() {
   var v = this.value.toUpperCase();
    if (colormapping.code2color[v]){
        inputA.value = colormapping.code2color[v];
    } else {
        inputA.value = '';
    }
}
colormapping = {
    color2code:{
       green : '#008000',
       red   : '#FF0000'
    },
    code2color:{
       '#008000':'green',
       '#FF0000':'red'
    }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
Name:<br />
<input id="color"><br />
Code:<br />
<input id="code">

</body>
</html>
```

This is how far I've come. The problem probably is my tags. Why is it not working? :/

Comment: This question is very generic and would probably be better at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Might be the case. Will post there. TY

Comment: @user1516844 This is almost certainly on-topic for SO, and probably off-topic for Programmers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following: **[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/poikl/GRLhW/)**

Basically, you need an Comparison Object, you can check against.

```
colormapping = {
    color2code:{
       green : '#008000',
       red   : '#FF0000'
    },
    code2color:{
       '#008000':'green',
       '#FF0000':'red'
    }
}​
```

And then the according event-listener:

```
inputA.onkeyup = function() {
   var v = this.value.toLowerCase();
   (colormapping.color2code[v])?
       inputB.value = colormapping.color2code[v]:
       inputB.value = '';
}
```

and vice versa for inputB:

```
inputB.onkeyup = function() {
   var v = this.value.toUpperCase();
    if (colormapping.code2color[v]){
        inputA.value = colormapping.code2color[v];
    } else {
        inputA.value = '';
    }   
}
```

Both have basically the same Code - the first one uses a [ternary if operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a) instead of the classical if.

(very advanced: If you want to make it nice, wrap it in an anonymous function to protect the mapping from alteration and avoid global namespace pollution.)

Comment: colormapping is a javascript object - you would write all that code you see in the example fiddle into `<script type="text/javascript> ...code here... </script>` Tags.

Comment: Alright. I have changed both of my input id's to input A and inputB. I tried to copy and paste it your code but it didn't work. What can be wrong?

Comment: @user1516844 you have to adjust the first to lines `var inputA = document.getElementById("<your Id here>");` to match the IDs of your elements.

Comment: I switched: `var v = this.value.toLowerCase();` to: `var inputA = document.getElementById("inputA");` Still doesn't work for me though. :/

Comment: @user1516844 nono, go to the example http://jsfiddle.net/jPPjr/7/ and try the code over there.

Comment: @user1516844 hey, what exactly is your problem? Which browser are you using? Press F12 and look into the console, are there any error messages?

Comment: It is solved now. The problem was that I had my input fields below my JS-code. Then the inputfields where null in the JS.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help. What I could understand is, when the value of input A changes, you want to change the value of input B. If it is :

```
var inputA = document.getElementById("inputA");
var inputB = document.getElementById("inputB");
inputA.onkeyup = function() {
   inputB.value = inputA.value
}
```

Check jsFiddle of how to do it. If this isn't what you want, feel free to downvote.

http://jsfiddle.net/9xeXC/

Comment: Not that simple I'm afraid. My explanation wasnt the best. I want the two different values to match eachother so when you type green another value (not green) will show. When you type the color-code for green I want the first input to realize that and automatically change its value to "green".

Comment: So instead of `inputB.value = inputA.value` you can change the `inputA.value` with the result that is going to be sent from the code.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the onchange event for javascript.

HTML:

`<input type="text" id="input1" onchange="input1_changed">` 
`<input type="text" id="input2" onchange="input2_changed">`

And in the javascript functions use a switch statement to change the other input based on the value of the changed input

Javascript:

```
function input1_changed() {
  var value = document.getElementById("input1").value;
  switch (value) {
    case "Green":
      document.getElementById("input2").value = "#00FF00";
      break;
    // continue for other colors
  }
}

function input2_changed() {
  var value = document.getElementById("input2").value;
  switch (value) {
    case "#00FF00":
      document.getElementById("input1").value = "Green";
      break;
    // continue for other values
  }
}
```

Comment: Your solution isn't wrong, but a keyed object (as in @Christoph's answer) is much more readable and less verbose than a `switch` statement. I don't say this to promote his answer (I point out his answer only so I don't have to write an example myself), but merely to point out a superior programming practice.

Comment: -1 for: event attributes + switch-case - you really should not teach a beginner such things. Btw, you have a typo in your code "value".